# ThinkPHP show my website as the req.host - did the request really come from my web server?

Tags: malware, phishing, remote-code-execution

I have ThinkPHP wordpress garbage coming at my server [https://medium.com/@knownsec404team/analysis-of-thinkphp5-remote-code-execution-vulnerability-](https://medium.com/@knownsec404team/analysis-of-thinkphp5-remote-code-execution-vulnerability-5de8a0afb2d4)5de8a0afb2d4
, for example:

```
/public/index.php?s=index/%5Cthink%5Capp/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars%5B0%5D=phpinfo&vars%5B1%5D%5B%5D=1
```

I logged this request using req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] to get the ip address, which I have logged as: **49.85.80.206**

I am also using req.get('host') to see who sent the request and it shows my website - let's call it **example.com**

Does this mean I have malware on my server, or it is more likely that the sender (taipei china) changed the 'host' in their cUrl request to appear to have come from my own server?

Comment: Are you running WordPress? Do the requests show a successful response code?

Comment: No I’m not running Wordpress. Just getting requests by some disrespectful foreign IP address (presumably they are aspiring to hurt any website they can get a hold of, not just mine)